# Swing ScrollTable issue

Tags: java, swing

I have a scroll table with four columns and the last column is editable. User can enter text into it and I want to restrict user to enter only 100 characters. Once the limit is reached, user should not be able to enter any more text into it.
Please suggest how can I solve this issue.
Thank you.

Comment: *"Swing ScrollTable.."* No such thing in the Swing package. Link to the Java Docs and please put more effort into questions.

Answer (score 2):

A JTable uses an editor to edit the text in a cell. The default editor is a JTextField, so you need to customize the text field to limit the text to 100 characters.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Implementing a DocumentFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) for working code that does this.

So then you need to create the editor and add it to the table. The basic code would be something like:

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField();
//add the DocumentFilter to the Document
DefaultCellEditor dce = new DefaultCellEditor( textField );
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(???).setCellEditor(dce);
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information about using tables and editors.