# In ScrollTable not able to resize table header and resize table when it's parent component is resized in java

Tags: java, swing

I have a Panel inside which I add a scroll table. I want this scroll table's header to be resizable (all columns should be able to resize and if table width exceeds panel width then a horizontal scroll bar should be displayed). Also if I resize the panel, scroll table should also be resized to fit the with of panel.
If I use AUTO_RESIZE_OFF for the table, I am able to resize header (columns) and a horizontal scroll bar is displayed but with this scroll table is not fit to panel's size when I resize the panel.

Adding a simple code base:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JTable table = new JTable();
table.getTableHeader().setResizingAllowed(true);
table.setAutoResizeMode(Auto_Resize_Off) // this is done to show     horizontal scroll bar when table's columns are resized
panel.add(table);
```

This allows me to resize my table's columns a display a horizontal scroll bar if table width is more than panel's width.
But when I resize the panel, it is not resizing the table also which I need.

Comment: *"I have a .."* For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36915896/swing-scrolltable-issue. 1) You got help in that question and never bothered to reply to the question. 2) You were also told there is no such thing as a "ScrollTable" and asked to put an effort into your questions.. Also the code you posted here will not work. 1) you don't add a table to a panel if you want it to scroll. 2) you can't use "Auto_Resize_Size" since the code won't compile.  So you don't appreciate the help when you get it and you are still not making an effort when asking a question. I'll skip this question.